# How do imports works in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I was looking at the React sample project and I just wondered what if I give `index.js`(default entry point in React) multiple `imports` including `App.js` and a custom user defined module like `A.js`.

So, in the next step I removed `ReactDOM.createRoot` from `index.js` and gave `App.js` and `A.js` each of them.

I put  `import "./A.js"` in `index.js` above `import "./App.js"`,
but still my program was rendering `App.js` first despite of the alphabetical order and their place in `src` folder. In every scale `A.js` should be rendered first, but still we got `App.js`. All of this processing is related to Webpack, so I was wondering what's going on under the hood?

`App.js`:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.</p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
     </div>
   );
 }

 const root2 = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
 root2.render(<App />);
```

`A.js`:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
const test=46;
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(test);
```

`index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './A.js';
import './index.css';
import './App';

import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
```

Comment: I don't quite follow your question. The order of imports is key here, because the "top-level" code in each module is run as soon as the `import` statement is encountered - and in your case, they both render content inside the `root` div, so the second one (`App` in this case) "wins" because the content of the `test` component is overwritten. (I'm not actually sure that this component is valid - a number is not a React component as I understand it.) I don't believe webpack comes into anything here.

Comment: om my bad... you're right the second one jus' overwrites the first one...